# Geofire query multiple references

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am making a taxi app and I use Geofire and Geoquery to get nearest drivers.

Now I have 3 types of cars "3 seats, 4 seats and 7 seats" and the user can switch between them, I want to change the query to get data from the correct reference.

My Code for reference and query:

```
refDrivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("drivers_locations_" + car_seats + "seat");
geoFireDrivers = new GeoFire(refDrivers);
geoQuery = geoFireDrivers.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(31.2551039, 30.0162619), 3);
```

where `car_seats` is the chosen car type by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the reference, you have to create a new instance of `GeoFire` and then query it again, just make sure to remove the listeners to the `GeoQuery` before attaching new listener.

There's no method to change the reference on the fly.

```
private GeoQuery geoQuery;

public void switchCarSeatType() {
    if (geoQuery != null) {
        // remove the previous listeners
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    }
    setGeoQuery(car_seats);
}

private void setGeoQuery(int car_seats) {
    refDrivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("drivers_locations_" + car_seats + "seat");
    geoFireDrivers = new GeoFire(refDrivers);
    geoQuery = geoFireDrivers.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(31.2551039, 30.0162619), 3);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener( ... );
}
```